# Prove the uniqueness of the matrix of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

How can i prove that the matrix that represents a linear transformation from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ is unique for a fixed basis of $V$ and $W$?

I have tried supposing that there exist a second matrix that represents the same linear transformation for these specific basis of $V$ and $W$ but i still do not know how to use this to prove the above statement.

Comment: If the representations are different then prove the some basis vector is linearly dependent on the others, contradicting that they're a basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $T\in\mathcal L(V,W)$ and $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is
a basis of $W$. The matrix of $T$ with respect to these bases is the $m$-by-$n$ matrix $\mathcal M(T)$ whose entries $A_{j,k}$ are defined by
$$\tag{*}\label{*}T(v_k)=\sum_{i=1}^mA_{i,k}w_i,$$
where $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Now, suppose that there exist a second matrix of $T$ (which we denote as the $m$-by-$n$ matrix $\mathcal N(T)$) with respect to the same bases and whose entries $B_{j,k}$ are defined by
$$\tag{**}\label{**}T(v_k)=\sum_{i=1}^mB_{i,k}w_i.$$
Substituting $(\ref{*})$ into $(\ref{**})$, we get
$$\tag{***}\label{***}\sum_{i=1}^mB_{i,k}w_i=\sum_{i=1}^mA_{i,k}w_i\implies\sum_{i=1}^m\left(B_{i,k}-A_{i,k}\right)w_i=0,$$
where $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Since $\{w_1,\ldots,w_m\}$ is linearly independent, it follows from $(\ref{***})$ that
$$B_{i,k}=A_{i,k},$$
where $i=1,\ldots,m$ and $k=1,\ldots,n$.

Therefore, $\mathcal M(T)=\mathcal N(T)$ and the matrix that represents a linear transformation with respect to a fixed basis of $V$ and $W$ is unique.